# MySQL LEFT JOIN where multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, where-clause, multiple-value

I have query that joins Products table on Product_Attributes table. I' would like to get products which meat exact condition ex.

Products which have attribute id 9 AND 16 selected, but when I run this query I'll get only product which meets first ID

```
WHERE ("AttributeValueID" = 9 AND "AttributeValueID" = 16)
```

I need that products to have both attributes selected `AttributeValueID = 9 AND  AttributeValueID = 9 not only this or that attribute ID.` Using `OR / IN` is'not solution for me.

Update:

below is a part of query with join / where:

LEFT JOIN "Product_Attributes" ON "Product_Attributes"."ProductID" = "SiteTree_Live"."ID" WHERE ("PriceTax" >= '100' AND "PriceTax" <= '200') AND ("AttributeValueID" IN ('9','8','7')) AND ("AttributeValueID" IN ('5','4'))

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: (It's not clear which table the columns in the WHERE clause refer to; because the column references aren't qualified with a table name or table alias. Is `PriceTax` a column from Product_Attributes or from SiteTree_Live?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon's answer showed the most flexible way to get the list of ProductId values that meet the specified criteria.

You could use a query like Gordon's (that gets the set of ProductId) as an inline view, and do a JOIN  operation against the products table, like this:

```
SELECT p.ProductID
     , p.ProductName
     , ...
  FROM products p
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT a.ProductID
           FROM ProductAttributes a
          GROUP BY a.ProductId
         HAVING SUM(a.AttributeValueID=9) > 0
            AND SUM(a.AttributeValueID=16) > 0
       ) s
     ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

---

**UPDATE**

based on the edit to the question adding a snippet of SQL text:

```
JOIN ( SELECT a.ProductID
         FROM Product_Attributes a
        HAVING SUM(a.AttributeValueID IN ('9','8','7')) > 0
           AND SUM(a.AttributeValueID IN ('5','4')) > 0
         GROUP BY a.ProductID
     ) s
   ON s.ProductID = SiteTree_Live.ID
WHERE SiteTree_Live.PriceTax >= '100'
  AND SiteTree_Live.PriceTax <= '200'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to solve these using `group by` and `having`, because that is a very flexible approach:

```
select pa.ProductId
from ProductAttributes pa
group by pa.ProductId
having sum(AttributeValueId = 9) > 0 and
       sum(AttributeValueId = 16) > 0;
```

Comment: +1. To get a JOIN to the `products` table, one option is to use a query like this one as an inline view (i.e. wrap this query in parens and assign it an alias, and reference that whole thing in the FROM/JOIN clause like it was a table.